# How can I fill free disk space with zeroes so that my virtualization host can stop thinking it's used?

Tags: filesystems

For my virtual machine host, I use Windows Server 2008r2 with role Hyper-V, while the guest VM is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It is located on a dynamic virtual hard disk (2TB). The size of this VM's VHD is 360 GB. But the real size shown within Ubuntu is about 50 GB.

It's apparently not possible to reduce the size of this VHD using standard Hyper-V tools, because the file system used by the Ubuntu VM is not NTFS.

Is there another way of doing it on Ubuntu that would result in resetting the free space on the VHD outside?

Comment: This probably isn't a Unix/Linux question. The problem you are having is finding the tool on the Windows Hypervisor to resize a virtual hard drive. Sounds like a Windows question.

Comment: no, the question is: "How can I fill the free space with zeroes in Ubuntu 12.04?"

I also do not have the internet on the machine with Linux.

Comment: After filling the free space with zeroes the file system will still not be NTFS so standard Hyper-V tools still will not work.  Either you're leaving something out or it's a Windows question.

Comment: If your hypervisor supports it (no idea if Hyper-V does), then `fstrim` may do what you want. With a *lot* less I/O, and far faster.

Comment: http://lwn.net/Articles/566769/ has a patch to make `fstrim` work. Not sure if/when it went into the mainline kernel, but that's fairly recent. If it works for you (or you're willing to patch your kernel to make it work), that's a FAR better solution.

Comment: Actually, since you're on Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1223499 it's fixed in Saucy. You could probably backport that patch to LTS, or maybe if you ask nicely Ubuntu will do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***UPDATE*** from 2019 (since someone upvoted and I noted it again)

Meanwhile the part of my answer that elaborates on `dd` use is correct by itself, *proper answer to the question how to let hypervisor know that there's some not-in-fact-occupied disk space inside its guest block storage is **to leverage TRIM/Discard commands***.

---

> How can I fill the free space with zeroes in Ubuntu 12.04 (ext4)?

It's rather simple:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/some/path/to/zerofile bs=128M count=NumOf128MBlocksToFillTheDiskWith`

You'd better have some space left untouched with that commands, say 1 %. By default `EXT…`FSes have special amount of reserved space for root user (AFAIR, 5 %), so in case you'd run this command as ordinary user, you won't fill up the whole disk, and that's great, since another system software running as `root` may malfunction in that case. But even running this `dd` as ordinary user you'd better not use the rest available space (95 %), otherwise other programms like, say Firefox, wouldn't be happy to realize they can't write to disk anymore and you may end up with inconsistent data. So leave the space untouched. It'd be even better to run this in single mode, then you'd squeeze the maximum and won't hurt anything.

After that, needless to say, but just in case — simply remove `/some/path/to/zerofile`.

P. S. Thanks to @[Weijian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/50846/weijian) for [sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99249/6622) info regarding `zerofree` which [does](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/zerofree.8.html) suit better for `EXT2`/`EXT3`/`EXT4`.

Comment: currently I'd say you need running `fstrim`

Answer (score 4):

in Ubuntu, you can use zerofree(http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/zerofree.8.html)

sudo aptitude install zerofree

**dd** is okay but may have some disadvantages according to the link above

Comment: Wow, thanks, it's always nice to find out there's better solution ;)

Comment: For zerofree to work (at least on Ubuntu 12 LTS), the filesystem has to be unmounted or mounted read-only, which means it's not really panacea.

Comment: For the record, zerofree only works on "ext2, ext3 and ext4 file-systems", so the requirement is probably not strictly "Ubuntu only" but it will not, for example, work for CentOS/RHEL if you're using the default XFS filesystem there.